# Recursively call an ajax function until the first ajax function is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parallel-processing

I have a python file which appends a result into log file and I need to print this log synchronously in UI.

Following is my code

```
var flag = 0;
function write_log_in_file(){
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "http://localhost/build5/builds/test.py",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "cache-control": "no-cache"
    }
  }
  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    flag =1;
    console.log(response);
  });
};

function get_log_from_file(){
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "http://localhost/build5/builds/build.log",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "cache-control": "no-cache"
    }
  }
  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
};

//Write build log in build.log file
write_log_in_file();

//Get log until python call is completed 
while(!flag){
  get_log_from_file();
}
```

Here, I have used flag variable, which is set to 1 after my first ajax call is completed. Until then my second ajax call is being called recursively.

Since I have used while, flag variable never becomes 1 and while goes in infinite loop.

Is there any other method, where I can recursively call my ajax function, while other ajax function is completed?

Comment: Removed the "python" tag because it has nothing to do with Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yury's answer is fine approach to using promises (you should look into it)

But the problem with your code is that there is no documented **.done** method in [JQuery's ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). You must use **.success**.

```
  $.ajax(settings)
  .success(function (response) {
    flag = 1;
    console.log(response);
  })
  .error(function(err) { 
    flag = -1; // End your while loop?
  });
```

Comment: Perfect this worked, though **.done** method is documented in their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`$.ajax` returns a promise you could chain.

```
function write_log_in_file(){
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "http://localhost/build5/builds/test.py",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
      "cache-control": "no-cache"
    }
  }
  return $.ajax(settings) // return a promise
};

function get_log_from_file(){
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "http://localhost/build5/builds/build.log",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "cache-control": "no-cache"
    }
  }
  return $.ajax(settings) // return a promise
};

//Write build log in build.log file
write_log_in_file()
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result) // log write result

    return get_log_from_file() // launch read
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result) // log read result
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
```